# Not able to cycle the images using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery and trying to cycle the images using JQuery Cycle function. But the code is not working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<style type="text/css">
.slideshow{padding: 70px;background-color: red;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/xampp1/htdocs/New Service Development Project/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="slideshow">
<img  src= "C:/xampp1/htdocs/New Service Development Project/images/i1.jpg">
<img  src= "C:/xampp1/htdocs/New Service Development Project/images/i2.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your Jquery-cycle plugin file..?

Comment: make the script references as related path.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has no cycle function, you will need to include some sort of cycle jquery plugin.
For example this: [Cycle jQuery plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/).

Include it after jQuery file.